# The container "…" must contain only one certificate and its private key

Tags: macos, ios

I am unable to install a mobile provisioning certificate on iOS 5 because I get this error:

`The container "…" must contain only one certificate and its private key.`

I used the same process that worked in the past but on iOS 5 it doesn't work and I have no idea how to export my certificate in a "desirable" state.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Development is off-topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by exporting the private key from the "Certificates" Category of Keychain, rather than exporting the Key directly.

[image: Certificates Category]

So export the NAME of the cert, not the private key itself, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more specific answer is that you...

- open up Keychain app
- (I am assuming you already have the key pair of your Identity in a keychain )
- Like @Brent Shaffer says, choosing from "Certificates" is more straight forward 
  (*The reason being is that the Keychain App logically groups the Certificate and private key for identities when using the "Certificates" view*)
- SHIFT-select both your SMIME certificate and its corresponding private key
- right-click the selection and choose 'Export 2 Items'
- Save as a (.p12) file with a very strong password
- email the .p12 file to your email account
- And from your iphone Mail app you can tap the .p12 file
- and Mail will suggest to import this as a Profile. You will need the password from earlier.